# Database Specific Migration Code using FluentMigrator

Tags: migration, fluent-migrator

**i am using fluentmigrator to create the database scripts, how can i run the database specific migration code using the fluentmigrator?**

Answer (score 0):

You can run as a command (As in, from command window), or as NANT or MSBUILD task.

Check details at:

https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/wiki/Migration-Runners

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of the **IfDatabase** method and **EmbeddedScript**.

See [the wiki entry about dealing with multiple database types](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/wiki/Dealing-with-Multiple-Database-Types)

Embed some .sql script files as resources and then use something like the snippet below.

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        IfDatabase("Oracle").Execute.EmbeddedScript("ora_do_work.sql");
        IfDatabase("SqlServer").Execute.EmbeddedScript("mssql_do_work.sql");
    }
```